# How to get Data from WPF Data Template with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Data template with textboxes in my xaml which is getting data from an observablecollection.

```
        <c:NameList x:Key="NameListData"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="NameItemTemplate" x:Name="CredentialsofDomains">
        <Border Name="BorderControl" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
            <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="DomainNameForCredentials" FontSize="18"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DomaineName}" Margin="0,0,40,0"></TextBlock>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="samAccountName"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Passwort"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="samAccountNameForCredentials" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=LoginName}" Width="100" />
                <TextBox x:Name="passwordForCredentials" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=PassWord}" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
                              <ListBox Width="auto"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NameListData}}"  
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameItemTemplate}"  
                                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
                                <Fluent:Button Name="saveDomainCredentials" SizeDefinition="Large" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Header="Speichern" Click="SaveDomainCredentials_Click"></Fluent:Button>
```

Now I want to get the displayed data on button click, how can I now get the values to my Click Event?

That's the Code Behind for my collection:

```
public partial class NameList : ObservableCollection<SetCredentialsForAD>
{
    public NameList() : base()
    {
        using var forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
        Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
        DomainCollection domains = currentForest.Domains;
        foreach (Domain objDomain in domains)
        {
            Add(new SetCredentialsForAD(objDomain.ToString(), "", ""));
        }
    }
}

public class SetCredentialsForAD
{
    private string loginName;
    private string passWord;
    private string domainName;

    public SetCredentialsForAD(string domain, string first, string last)
    {
        this.domainName = domain;
        this.loginName = first;
        this.passWord = last;
    }

    public string DomaineName
    {
        get { return domainName; }
        set { domainName = value; }
    }

    public string LoginName
    {
        get { return loginName; }
        set { loginName = value; }
    }

    public string PassWord
    {
        get { return passWord; }
        set { passWord = value; }
    }
}
```

And now I need to safe the values to settings to use them later in my App
Each active directory domain needs a name and password, that's what I'm trying to solve.

to get a message for each founded item as validItem:

```
private void SaveDomainCredentials_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in ListBox.SelectedItems.OfType<SetCredentialsForAD>())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Domaine: " + item.DomaineName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the code for the data source?  Is this in the code behind of the Xaml file?  Based on what you have shown that would seem to be the case.

Assuming these assumptions are correct you would need to use the SelectedItem of the ListBox.  So need to give the ListBox and x:Name.  And in the event handler would use:

```
MyListBoxName.SelectedItem
```

To get the Item

I do not know anything about setting up the Domain information using the Forest.  But if you use the SelectedItem you get a SetCredentialsForAD object.

Using

```
    public NameList() : base()
    {

        Add(new SetCredentialsForAD("domain 1", "name 1", "pwd 1"));
        Add(new SetCredentialsForAD("domain 2", "name 2", "pwd 2"));
        Add(new SetCredentialsForAD("domain 3", "name 3", "pwd 3"));
        Add(new SetCredentialsForAD("domain 4", "name 4", "pwd 4"));
    }
```

Then in the click handler I can cast the SelectedItem to a SetCredentialsForAD object

```
    if ( ListBox.SelectedItem is SetCredentialsForAD item )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.DomaineName);
        Console.WriteLine(item.LoginName);
        Console.WriteLine(item.PassWord);
    }
```

SelectedItems is a List of SetCredentialsForAD objects.  You need to cast the items in the List to the proper object type.  Your code would not even compile, you cannot create a variable with the same name twice.  To do what you want would be

```
    private void SaveDomainCredentials_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in ListBox.SelectedItems.OfType<SetCredentialsForAD>())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Domaine: " + item.DomaineName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: with that approach i get the name of the class SetCredentialsForAD, more then before :) but not all I need.

Comment: Joe H. that gives me the desired data, thank you so much. But if I hit now my button under the List, to save whole data, Ive entered in my textBox for each domain, I receive only the first item for domain1.

Comment: You are using a ListBox, so only one item is selected at a time.  If you change the selected item you would get that one (i.e, 2 or 3).  You could setup a ListBox to allow multiple items to be selected.  In that case you would use the SelectedItems property and iterate through the items

Comment: Ive setup the multiselect and I can now multiselect entrys in my listbox.  Now I try to use a foreach to get every list entry to store into db, Ive posted my try above.